# Can I get the action in the before() method of a controller in Kohana 3?

Tags: php, kohana

My controller has...

```
class Controller_Staff extends Controller {

    public function before() {
       parent::before();
       $id = $this->request->param('id');
       $action = $this->request->param('action');
    }
    
    public function action_get($id) {
       var_dump($id);
    }

}
```

My route is...

```
Route::set('a', 'bla/<action>/<id>',
            array('id' => '\d+', 'action' => '(get|set)'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'staff',
        'action' => 'set'
    ));
```

When I enter a URL (`bla/get/42`) which calls `Controller_Staff->before()` (before calling `action_get()`),  I can access `$id` in `before()`, but `$action` is always `NULL`.

Is there a better way to access the current `$action` in the `before()` method?

Comment: you're calling before() method on a simple controller? isn't that supposed to exist only on the template one's?

Comment: @yoda I didn't think so. I wanted to place code that was run for every action, so it seemed like a good place to put it.

Comment: hmm .. thought (and was told at IRC) that before() and after() methods belonged to controller_template .. gotta dig that out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

It ended up being *very* easy.

```
$action = $this->request->action;
```

Comment: lost count of how many times things were easy and I still get lost looking for them .. kohana rocks :)

Comment: In Kohana 3.3 (dunno when they changed it, maybe an earlier version than that) it's a function not a property: $this->request->action()